# Changing category slug messes incoming links to posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have wordpress site on say: `http://xyz.com/category-name/`

now I changed the category slug to `new-category-name`

When I paste this in the browser:

```
http://xyz.com/category-name/post-name/
```

it redirects me to

```
http://xyz.com/new-category-name/
```

instead of

```
http://xyz.com/new-category-name/post-name/
```

I already tried

something like:

```
RewriteRule ^category-name/(.*) http://xyz.com/new-category-name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it does not work...
how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the server cached the old .htaccess for a while. Now it started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the redirection plugin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

One of the most powerful features is it tracks changes in post URL's and creates 301 redirects to the new pages automatically... saved me a ton of work.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I already found what the trouble is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13404806/385402 but I could use this plugin in another situation

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the permalink structure going to Settings->Permalinks.